# Windows deleted my linux partition

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot

So I had three systems on my computer. ElementaryOS (linux) and two windows 8.1 systems. It booted up always to GRUB at first. It aleays showed two options:

1. elementaryOS
2. Windows 8

When I booted into Windows option, the mbr asked me which winodws systems among two I wanna run. I used mainly one of them so I decided it's time to change it and delete one system. I entered *Disk Management* on the main Windows system and deleted the partition with the second Windows. And somehow that method also deleted Linux partition. The two additional system were mounted on a logical partition:

1. First came Linux with 30GB partition
2. Second was the data disk (around 150GB), which is fine btw.
3. At the end was additional W8.1 system 60GB

My question is: Why Windows made Linux partition dispear?

P.S. Sorry for partitiongeddon and I am currently repairing grub through LiveUSB with Linux

Comment: If you used a Windows partitioning software, then it would write the MBR and Windows bootloader to load the OS. Unfortunately, it knows nothing about Linux and will ignore that partition. If your data is on a NTFS partition, it should have recognized that one so you have access to it in Windows. You should be able to fix the problem with Boot-Repair: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @LDC3 Thank you very much. It explains much of the fuss.

Comment: I haven't looked at it in depth since Windows Vista or perhaps 7, but the built-in Windows partitioning software is (or at least was) extremely buggy when it comes to handling extended and logical partitions. The Ubuntu forums were rife with such reports a few years ago. You may be able to recover your partitions using [TestDisk.](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) Thereafter, I suggest you not use the standard Windows partitioning tools except if you need to shrink your NTFS volumes.

Comment: @RodSmith I usually use GParted on LiveUSB. I wanted to save time and that's why I'm mad at myself. I have already installed new distro and its awesome. Thanks guys!